# X, along with Y and others, "were" or "was"?

Tags: verb-agreement

There is an earlier exchange on this, but one that does not include "and others" and that uses only the verb "to be." My question:

What if it were "Joan, along with Jake and others" and the verb were not "to be," but a regular transitive verb? For example, "bake": Joan, along with Jake and others, bake/s cakes every Saturday. Would the singular still be absolutely necessary, or would plural be acceptable usage as well?

Comment: Why do you think the addition of _and others_ changes things? As the answers to the other question say, the “in addition to/along with/as well as X” phrase is considered parenthetical; you can remove it for purposes of grammar and syntax. When you remove the entire thing, it doesn’t matter whether it includes “and his brother” or “and others” or even “and everyone else in the entire known universe” – however many ‘others’ there are, they get removed as well. Since this is already in the existing question, I’ve voted to consider this one as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Yes, of course that would be the answer of a prescriptive grammarian, which in most cases I also am. However, there are limits, and it is a matter of 'feel' as much as a matter of rules in a case like this. By the time you've gotten to the second name and then to "the others," the subject 'sense,' as it were, is very much plural, so that "bake," while still technically wrong, is not wrong in terms of acceptable usage. In any case, that is my position. It would be interesting to learn what others, less absolutely prescriptive, might think.

Comment: Anything parenthetical is ignored when it comes to grammar. That's an absolute rule. In your sentence, only *was* is grammatical. There's no debating the use of that word. However, if it makes what you read *awkward*, then ***rephrase the sentence***: *X was Z, as were Y and others.* Or *Y and others, along with X, were Z.* Or *X, Y, and others were Z.*

Comment: Such rules can be absolute, until, that is, there's a good syntactical or stylistic reason for breaking them. This is such a case. It sounds awkward with the singular, but just fine with the plural. Your alternatives: 1) X bakes cakes every Saturday, as do Y and others; 2) Y and others, along with X, bake cakes every S; or 3) X, Y, and others bake cakes every S. 1 requires the addition of the emphatic, which might work with this simple sentence, but becomes awkward if there are more objects, adverbs, etc. 2 and 3 change the sense and all three the rhythm, not for the better.